# Maintain a hardware handle beyond program termination

Tags: multithreading, qt

First off, I realize that it is impossible to maintain a variable past program termination.  Here is the situation...I have an FPGA on the PCI bus that controls a number of mechanical devices on a machine.  When the session handle terminates the FPGA IO goes to a random state.  This causes a number of mechanical problems.

One thought I had is to put the session handle in a worker thread and detach the worker thread. After researching this I discovered that the worker terminates when the application terminates.

I have seen others discuss processes that don't terminate but that seems like a bad idea to me.

Are there any other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Try to run a process in a cron job.

Comment: Are you trying to extend the life of an application beyond the life of that application?

Comment: No, I am not "trying to extend the life of an application beyond the life of that application".  The FPGA does not offer a way to keep a session running without a valid application attached to it.  Therefore, if the application dies for some unexpected reason the FPGA session terminates.  I would like to keep that session handle valid somehow.

Comment: Sounds like you need a kernel module (a driver).

Comment: A device driver or a service / daemon would be good options.

Comment: Maybe you need a companion process to keep this thing active. It could be a background service you can communicate with using IPC.

Comment: This seems like something that should be fixed in the FPGA.  e.g. a watchdog in the FPGA that detects that the host has disconnected, that shuts down the connected hardware in an orderly manner.

Answer (score 0):

After considering a number of solutions, I ended up overriding the open and close session behavior in the FPGA to not reset after the last session closes.